# how to best secure controllers actions and display different content symfony2

Tags: symfony

I'm building a web application using symfony2. I have different types of users with different roles; ROLE_STUDENT and ROLE_TEACHER, those two user can access a course's details; if the user is a teacher, a button edit is shown and if it's the student then a button subscribe will be shown, and actually this is not secure because it just hides the path to the controllers action, if the student types in the address bar /course/2/edit the edit action would be executed so I had to secure the action using @security annotation:

This is what I have done so far:

```
/**
 * @Security("has_role('ROLE_TEACHER')")
 */    public function editAction()
      {}
```

and in twig :

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_TEACHER') %} 
   <a href="{{path('edit', {'id': course.id})}}">edit</a>
{% elseif is_granted('ROLE_STUDENT')%}
   <a href="{{path('subscribe', {'id': course.id})}}">subscribe</a>
```

.

The problem is that I have a lot of accessible content to both users and I think there is a better solution to this instead of copy/past the same code all over. I'm new to Symfony 2, please bear with me.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to achieve this but what you are doing is not wrong.

One way to achieve this is to set `ROLE` for the `ROUTES` so that ROLE_STUDENT roles can only access URLs that will be something like this `website.com/students` and ROLE_TEACHER can only access `website.com/teachers`

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/student/, roles: ROLE_STUDENT }
    - { path: ^/teamleader/, roles: ROLE_TEACHER }
```

You can then set the edit route only for teachers like `website.com/teachers/course/2/edit` this way no edit route is going to be available for `ROLE_STUDENT` and they will get 404 error or access denied error if they try to access teacher route. You can do the same for the subscribe feature.

Like I said there are more ways to achieve this and this is one of them.